# How to access children's data of a GridLayout without using the ids of children in kivymd

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am working on my new app.
In this app, I made a function called `func_physics` in python which adds `MDcards` to a `MDGridLayout` containing a `MDLabel`.

Now in `func_physics` if I add `MDlabel`'s `id`, it gives an error saying that "In `id=mylabel` mylabel is not defined. Because it's not a string but in kv language we are not supposed to use strings for ids....

So I didn't gave that MDLabel an `id`

Now, I need to access MDLabel's text .. So how do I do that without using its `id`.

So Now i wanna know that, is there any way of accessing `GridLayout`'s children's data without using the children's `id`

**Any response is very much appreciated.. Thank you**

Comment: In your `func_physics()` method, you can maintain a list or dictionary of the created `MDcards`.

Comment: Please post minimal working code that shows the problem.